# VSTS Task - Azure RM Service Reference

Tags: azure-devops

I'm working on VSTS Task which will populate input data from AzureRM. Anyone know help to find out the data binding reference (marked as xxxxxxx)? I would like to get data about automation account, but i wasn't able to find it. Many thanks.

```
"inputs":[
    {
        "name": "ConnectedServiceName",
        "type": "connectedService:AzureRM",
        "label": "Azure RM Subscription",
        "required": true,
        "helpMarkDown": "Azure Resource Manager subscription",
    },
    {
        "name": "ResourceGroupName",
        "label": "Resource Group",
        "type": "pickList",
        "required": true,
        "helpMarkDown": "Provide the name of a resource group.",
        "properties": {
        "EditableOptions": "True"
    },
    {
        "name": "AutomationAccount",
        "type": "pickList",
        "label": "Automation Account Name",
        "required": true,
        "helpMarkDown": "Select or Type Automation Account Name",
        "properties": {
            "EditableOptions": "True"
        }
    }
],
"dataSourceBindings": [
    {
        "target": "ResourceGroupName",
        "endpointId": "$(ConnectedServiceName)",
        "dataSourceName": "AzureResourceGroups"
    },
    {
        "target": "AutomationAccount",
        "endpointId": "$(ConnectedServiceName)",
        "dataSourceName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found it. In REST Api of the AzureRM Service Endpoint

```
    "dataSources":  [
                        "@{name=TestConnection; endpointUrl={{{endpoint.url}}}/subscriptions/{{{endpoint.subscriptionId}}}?api-version=2016-06-01; resourceUrl=; resultSelector=jsonpath:$}",
                        "@{name=AzureResourceGroups; endpointUrl={{{endpoint.url}}}/subscriptions/{{{endpoint.subscriptionId}}}/resourcegroups?api-version=2016-02-01; resourceUrl=; resultSelector=jsonpath:$.value[*].name}",
                        "@{name=AzureStorageAccountRM; endpointUrl={{{endpoint.url}}}/subscriptions/{{{endpoint.subscriptionId}}}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts?api-version=2015-06-15; resourceUrl=; resultSelector=jsonpath:$.value[*].name}",
                        "@{name=AzureRMStorageAccountByLocation; endpointUrl={{{endpoint.url}}}/subscriptions/{{{endpoint.subscriptionId}}}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts?api-version=2015-06-15; resourceUrl=; resultSelector=jsonpath:$.value[?(@.location ==\u0027{{location}}\u0027)].name}",
                        "@{name=AzureRMStorageAccountIdByName; endpointUrl={{{endpoint.url}}}/subscriptions/{{{endpoint.subscriptionId}}}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts?api-version=2015-06-15; resourceUrl=; resultSelector=jsonpath:$.value[?(@.name ==\u0027{{storageAccountName}}\u0027)].id}",
                        "@{name=AzureVirtualMachinesV2Id; endpointUrl={{{endpoint.url}}}/subscriptions/{{{endpoint.subscriptionId}}}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2015-06-15; resourceUrl=; resultSelector=jsonpath:$.value[*].id}",
                        "@{name=AzureRMWebAppNames; endpointUrl={{{endpoint.url}}}/subscriptions/{{{endpoint.subscriptionId}}}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites?api-version=2015-08-01; resourceUrl=; resultSelector=jsonpath:$.value[*].name}",
                        "@{name=AzureRMServerfarmId; endpointUrl={{{endpoint.url}}}/subscriptions/{{{endpoint.subscriptionId}}}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites?api-version=2015-08-01; resourceUrl=; resultSelector=jsonpath:$.value[?(@.name==\u0027{{WebAppName}}\u0027)].properties}",
                        "@{name=AzureAppKind; endpointUrl={{{endpoint.url}}}/subscriptions/{{{endpoint.subscriptionId}}}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites?api-version=2015-08-01; resourceUrl=; resultSelector=jsonpath:$.value[?(@.name==\u0027{{WebAppName}}\u0027)].properties}",
                        "@{name=AzureRMWebAppKind; endpointUrl={{{endpoint.url}}}/{{{ServerfarmId}}}?api-version=2015-08-01; resourceUrl=; resultSelector=jsonpath:$}",
                        "@{name=AzureRMWebAppResourceGroup; endpointUrl={{{endpoint.url}}}/subscriptions/{{{endpoint.subscriptionId}}}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites?api-version=2015-08-01; resourceUrl=; resultSelector=jsonpath:$.value[?(@.name==\u0027{{WebAppName}}\u0027)].properties.resourceGroup}",
                        "@{name=AzureRMWebAppSlotsId; endpointUrl={{{endpoint.url}}}/subscriptions/{{{endpoint.subscriptionId}}}/resourceGroups/{{{ResourceGroupName}}}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$(WebAppName)/slots?api-version=2015-08-01; resourceUrl=; resultSelector=jsonpath:$.value[*].id}",
                        "@{name=AzureRMLoadBalancers; endpointUrl={{{endpoint.url}}}/subscriptions/{{{endpoint.subscriptionId}}}/resourceGroups/{{{ResourceGroupName}}}/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers?api-version=2016-09-01; resourceUrl=; resultSelector=jsonpath:$.value[*].name}",
                        "@{name=AzureLocations; endpointUrl={{{endpoint.url}}}/subscriptions/$(endpoint.subscriptionId)/locations?api-version=2016-09-01; resourceUrl=; resultSelector=jsonpath:$.value[*].displayName}",
                        "@{name=AzureLocations2; endpointUrl={{{endpoint.url}}}/subscriptions/$(endpoint.subscriptionId)/locations?api-version=2016-09-01; resourceUrl=; resultSelector=jsonpath:$.value[*]}",
                        "@{name=AzureRMContainerRegistries; endpointUrl={{{endpoint.url}}}/subscriptions/{{{endpoint.subscriptionId}}}/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries?api-version=2017-03-01; resourceUrl=; resultSelector=jsonpath:$.value[*]}",
                        "@{name=AzureKeyVaults; endpointUrl={{{endpoint.url}}}/subscriptions/{{{endpoint.subscriptionId}}}/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults?api-version=2016-10-01; resourceUrl=; resultSelector=jsonpath:$.value[*].name}",
                        "@{name=AzureKeyVaultsList; endpointUrl={{{endpoint.url}}}/subscriptions/{{{endpoint.subscriptionId}}}/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults?api-version=2016-10-01; resourceUrl=; resultSelector=jsonpath:$.value[*]}",
                        "@{name=AzureKeyVaultListVaults; endpointUrl={{{endpoint.url}}}/subscriptions/{{{endpoint.subscriptionId}}}/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults?api-version=2016-10-01; resourceUrl=; resultSelector=jsonpath:$}",
                        "@{name=AzureKeyVaultListVaultsWithSkipToken; endpointUrl={{{endpoint.url}}}/subscriptions/{{{endpoint.subscriptionId}}}/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults?api-version=2016-10-01\u0026$skiptoken={{{SkipToken}}}; resourceUrl=; resultSelector=jsonpath:$}",
                        "@{name=AzureKeyVaultListSecretsTestConnection; endpointUrl=https://{{{KeyVaultName}}}.{{{endpoint.AzureKeyVaultDnsSuffix}}}/secrets?maxresults=1\u0026api-version=2016-10-01; resourceUrl={{{endpoint.AzureKeyVaultServiceEndpointResourceId}}}; resultSelector=jsonpath:$}",
                        "@{name=AzureKeyVaultGetSecretTestConnection; endpointUrl=https://{{{KeyVaultName}}}.{{{endpoint.AzureKeyVaultDnsSuffix}}}/secrets/nonexistingrandomsecretname?api-version=2016-10-01; resourceUrl={{{endpoint.AzureKeyVaultServiceEndpointResourceId}}}; resultSelector=jsonpath:$}",
                        "@{name=AzureKeyVaultSecrets; endpointUrl=https://{{{KeyVaultName}}}.{{{endpoint.AzureKeyVaultDnsSuffix}}}/secrets?api-version=2016-10-01; resourceUrl={{{endpoint.AzureKeyVaultServiceEndpointResourceId}}}; resultSelector=jsonpath:$}",
                        "@{name=AzureKeyVaultSecretsWithSkipToken; endpointUrl=https://{{{KeyVaultName}}}.{{{endpoint.AzureKeyVaultDnsSuffix}}}/secrets?api-version=2016-10-01\u0026$skiptoken={{{SkipToken}}}; resourceUrl={{{endpoint.AzureKeyVaultServiceEndpointResourceId}}}; resultSelector=jsonpath:$}",
                        "@{name=AzureVirtualMachineScaleSetNames; endpointUrl={{{endpoint.url}}}/subscriptions/{{{endpoint.subscriptionId}}}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets?api-version=2017-03-30; resourceUrl=; resultSelector=jsonpath:$.value[*].name}",
                        "@{name=AzureRMDependencyData; endpointUrl={{{endpoint.url}}}/metadata/endpoints?api-version=1.0; resourceUrl=; resultSelector=jsonpath:$}"
                    ],
```

Comment: Where did you find this? I can't find any documentation stating what is available in dataSourceBindings from a `connectedService:AzureRM`

Comment: exported from API. Everything in Azure is formatted and sent to API. So anything what is not in it is not in documentation is described in API

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a blog post on service endpoints available: [Service endpoints – Data sources](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sriramb/2016/09/15/service-endpoints-data-sources/)

Looks like you can also perform the same Rest call as the service endpoint to retrieve the entire structure with

```
https://YourVSTSSubscription.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_apis/distributedtask/serviceendpointtypes?type=AzureRM
```